# adjusting row height in ggplot lollipop

Tags: r, ggplot2

I need some help formatting my lollipop graph.
The rows are too far apart from each other, with too much white space in each row therefore the top and bottom lines are too close to the edges of the plot.
Ive tried adjusting a few formatting things in the plotting and the theme, but seem to be going in circles.
Any help appreciated.
Thanks

```
> dput(data)
structure(list(Type = c("Programming", "Programming", "Analytics", 
"Professional", "Applied Science", "Applied Science", "Programming", 
"Analytics", "Professional", "Programming", "Analytics", "Professional", 
"Applied Science", "Analytics", "Professional", "Applied Science"
), Skill = c("Python", "Other", "Databases", "Project Management", 
"NGS", "Environmental Engineering", "Perl", "Bioinformatics", 
"Teaching", "R", "Statistics", "Supervision", "Microbiome", "Visualization", 
"Science Communication", "Applied Microbiology"), Of.5 = c(4, 
4, 4.5, 4.5, 4, 4, 4.5, 4.5, 4.5, 4.7, 4.5, 4.5, 4.5, 4.7, 4.5, 
4.7), Of.10 = c(7.5, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8.5, 8.5, 8.5, 9, 9, 9, 9, 
9.5, 9.5, 9.5)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -16L
))

data<-datAnal_skills

skills_lolli_plot_corrOrder<-function(data){
  ## reordering data within each facet
  dat2 <- data %>% 
    # 1. Remove grouping
    ungroup() %>% 
    # 2. Arrange by
    #   i.  facet group (tissue)
    #   ii. value (score)
    arrange(Type, Of.10) %>%
    # 3. Add order column of row numbers
    mutate(order = row_number())
  ###
  ggplot(dat2, aes(order, Of.10)) +
    geom_segment(aes(xend = order, yend = 0), 
                 colour = "grey",lwd=1.5) +
    geom_point(size = 8, col = "#f39c12") + 
    geom_text(aes( label = Of.10),  size = 4,color="white")+
    ylim(c(0,10))+
    scale_x_continuous(
      breaks = dat2$order,
      labels = dat2$Skill) +
    coord_flip()+
    facet_wrap(~Type,scales='free_y')+
    labs(
      x = "",
      y = "",
      title = ""
    ) +
    theme_bw() +
    theme(
      axis.text.x=element_blank(),
      axis.ticks = element_blank(),
      panel.grid.major.x = element_blank(),
      panel.grid.minor.x = element_blank(),
      panel.grid.major.y = element_line(colour = "grey60", linetype = "dashed"),
      axis.text.y = element_text(size=14),legend.text=element_text(size=14),strip.text=element_text(size=14)          # increase label text size
    ) 
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can expand the scale using, e.g. `expand = expansion(0, 0.5)` inside the `scale_x_continuous()` function:

```r
skills_lolli_plot_corrOrder<-function(data){
  ## reordering data within each facet
  dat2 <- data %>% 
    # 1. Remove grouping
    ungroup() %>% 
    # 2. Arrange by
    #   i.  facet group (tissue)
    #   ii. value (score)
    arrange(Type, Of.10) %>%
    # 3. Add order column of row numbers
    mutate(order = row_number())
  ###
  ggplot(dat2, aes(order, Of.10)) +
    geom_segment(aes(xend = order, yend = 0), 
                 colour = "grey",lwd=1.5) +
    geom_point(size = 8, col = "#f39c12") + 
    geom_text(aes( label = Of.10),  size = 4,color="white")+
    ylim(c(0,10))+
    scale_x_continuous(
      breaks = dat2$order,
      labels = dat2$Skill,
      expand = expansion(0, 0.5)) +
    coord_flip()+
    facet_wrap(~Type,scales='free_y')+
    labs(
      x = "",
      y = "",
      title = ""
    ) +
    theme_bw() +
    theme(
      axis.text.x=element_blank(),
      axis.ticks = element_blank(),
      panel.grid.major.x = element_blank(),
      panel.grid.minor.x = element_blank(),
      panel.grid.major.y = element_line(colour = "grey60", linetype = "dashed"),
      axis.text.y = element_text(size=14),legend.text=element_text(size=14),strip.text=element_text(size=14)          # increase label text size
    ) 
}
```

which gives:

[image: Lollipop chart]

You can play around with the values inside the `expansion()` function to get exactly what you want.